# Verificar se objeto ja existe no array pelo id

Tags: javascript

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto, onde um usuário vai montar uma lista de contratos, pesquisando pelo cpf, só que se ele pesquisar pelo mesmo cpf 2 vezes, o contrato se repete na lista, como eu faço pra verificar se o contrato ja existe na lista `array` e impedir de ele ser inserido

```
    $scope.contratos = [];
   $scope.Pesquisar = function(){
   $http.post('php/GetContratosProtocolo.php', {
  'cpf':cpf
   }).success(function(data){
  if(typeof data == 'object'){  
      $scope.contratos.push(data)
  }else{
  showerror('Contrato Não Encontrado')
   }

    }).error(function(data){
  console.log(data)
   })
   }
```

Comment: Mais detalhes.. o que contém `data[i]`?

Comment: por exemplo... nome:luiz | cpf: 111.111.111-11| id: 1

Comment: eu to fazendo esse for, porque data pode vim com 2 objetos, entao eu jogo o data[0], data[1] dentro do array, e to fazendo um push porque o usuario vai montar uma lista, entao conforme ele vai pesquisando pelo cpf, vai inserindo na lista

Comment: Luiz: Este codigo é insuficiente para nós te podermos ajudar :)

Comment: vou tentar reformular minha pergunta

Answer (score 2):

Toda vez que o utilizador procurar pelo CPF, uma ligação com o servidor será estabelecida, mesmo se tratando de um CPF já pesquisado e isso é desnecessário, pois essa informação pode ser guardada no lado do cliente.

O que sugiro no código abaixo é que o CPF seja incluído como índice do array `contratos`, o que faz sentido porque atualmente cada objeto dentro do array `contratos` se refere a um CPF e é justamente a duplicação que você quer evitar:

```
$scope.contratos = [];
$scope.Pesquisar = function(){
   //verifica se o CPF é um índice do array contratos 
   //e só faz um novo request se o CPF ainda não foi pesquisado.
   if(typeof $scope.contratos[cpf] === 'undefined') {
       $http.post('php/GetContratosProtocolo.php', {
          'cpf':cpf
       })
       .success(function(data){
          if(typeof data == 'object'){  
              //adiciona um novo elemento ao array utilizando o CPF como índice.
              $scope.contratos[cpf] = data;
          }else{
              //adiciona na mesma o CPF no array de contratos, embora o resultado seja `null`, não deixa de ser uma resposta válida.
              $scope.contratos[cpf] = null;
              showerror('Contrato Não Encontrado')
          }
       })
       .error(function(data){
           console.log(data)
       })
   }
};
```

Depois para extrair os dados do array `contratos` basta fazer um `forEach`:

```
$scope.contratos.forEach(function(value, key) {
     //key = cpf utilizado como índice
     //...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Luiz, eu sugiro usar o método `contains` da array para verificar se o objeto já existe na array antes de dar o `push`:

```
$scope.contratos = [];
$scope.Pesquisar = function(){
$http.post('php/GetContratosProtocolo.php', {
  'cpf':cpf
  }).success(function(data){
    if(typeof data == 'object'){  
      if($scope.contratos.contains(data))
      {
        showerror('Contrato Já Registrado')
      }else{
        $scope.contratos.push(data)
      }
    }else{
      showerror('Contrato Não Encontrado')
    }
  }).error(function(data){
    console.log(data)
  })
}
```

Font: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains

**Edit:** Me desculpe, esse recurso ainda está em experimento e não existe nativamente. Para que funcione, é necessário executar antes:

```
if (![].contains) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'contains', {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: function(searchElement/*, fromIndex*/) {
      if (this === undefined || this === null) {
        throw new TypeError('Cannot convert this value to object');
      }
      var O = Object(this);
      var len = parseInt(O.length) || 0;
      if (len === 0) { return false; }
      var n = parseInt(arguments[1]) || 0;
      if (n >= len) { return false; }
      var k;
      if (n >= 0) {
        k = n;
      } else {
        k = len + n;
        if (k < 0) k = 0;
      }
      while (k < len) {
        var currentElement = O[k];
        if (searchElement === currentElement ||
            searchElement !== searchElement && currentElement !== currentElement
        ) {
          return true;
        }
        k++;
      }
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: _$scope.contratos.contains is not a function_ ta dando esse erro

Comment: Eu notei isso em um teste que fiz agora. Eu editei a resposta com mais informações.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma simples com poucas alterações seria criar uma nova função para verificar se a array já possui o valor e chamar ela em uma condição antes de adicionar:

```
function contains(array,value)
{
    var doescontain = false;
    array.forEach(function(element){
        if(element == value)
        {
            doescontain = true;
        }
    },this);
    return doescontain;
}
```

Colocando na sua condição ficaria assim:

```
if(typeof data == 'object'){  
  if(contains($scope.contratos,data))
  {
    showerror('Contrato Já Registrado')
  }else{
     $scope.contratos.push(data)
  }
}else{
   showerror('Contrato Não Encontrado')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma

```
      if(typeof data == 'object'){

    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
      var objExiste = $.grep($scope.contratos, function(n, x){
                    return n.idcontrato == data[i].idcontrato;
                  })

                  if(objExiste.length == 0){
                     $scope.contratos.push(data[i])
                   } else {
          console.log('contrato ja inserido')
      }

        }


}else{
  showerror('Contrato Não Encontrado')
}
```